# Excel: Highlight column header that contains non NULL values

Tags: excel

I need to highlight column headers that do not have blanks. 
Example:

- I have three columns Student ID, Year and Major
- Student ID has blanks
- Year and Major columns do not have blanks. So I need to highlight these columns

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I haven't tried Vasim. I'm looking for a solution. Let me give you the problem statement. I need to compare two excel sheets containing hundreds of rows and tens of columns. I am able to compare the data and display the differences using the formula [ =IF(Sheet1!A2<> Sheet2!A2, "Sheet1:"&Sheet1!A2&" vs Sheet2:"&Sheet2!A2, "") ]. Now I need to report the columns having data mismatches

Comment: Welcome to SO @Ravi! Unfortunately this isn't a code writing service, so you're going to need to give some more detail of what you've tried and what exactly is giving you a problem for people to be able to help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and look through [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already, then see if you can improve your question and I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formating using:

- Excel Table feature (CTRL+T)
- ROWS formula (returns a number of rows in a range)
- COUNTA formula (returns number of cells that are not empty)
- Named ranges for columns in Table (select all cells in column and name it. In example below the Year columns is called Years)

[image]